# Rails: build array with the value from a certain model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an model called 'Notation' with the attributes 'name' and 'tag'
In its controller there is an action that will return an json with the array with all 'tag' value (the 'tag' value from all model's records).

I have implemented this:

```
@tags = Notation.all.map{ |notation| notation.tag }
render json: @tags
```

this works, but I checked in the console and saw the SQL that has been queried:

```
SELECT "notations".* FROM "notations"
```

I was wondering if there is another way using ActiveRecord to query only the 'tag' attribute (mostly because of performances issues), or if this is something I do not have to worry about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `all`, then you're getting all the attributes from the model.

You could use `select` and ask only for the tag attribute, and you would give a query like "`SELECT "notations"."tag" FROM "notations"`" but you would get a `Notation::ActiveRecord_Relation` object type, and you should have to use map to get only an array with the needed attribute.

```
Visit.select(:name).map(&:name)
```

To skip the `map` part to create an array, you could use pluck like:

```
@tags = Notation.pluck :tag
render json: @tags
```

And this should also query only for the `tag` attribute from the Notation objects:

```
SELECT "notations"."tag" FROM "notations"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are few ways to achieve this 
1) Use `pluck` method

```
@tags = Notation.pluck(:tag)
render json: @tags
```

here is source https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

2) use Select method

```
@tags = Notation.select(:tag).map(&:tag) (here convert ActiveRecord Relation object to Array)
render json: @tags
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select

here is difference between pluck vs select, if you want to explore more.
https://medium.com/@amliving/activerecords-select-pluck-3d5c58872053